# Why locale did not supported in project?

Tags: commercetools

I recently work with Commercetools platform and I have a question.

I'm trying to create cart with locale, but when I do this I've got error.

> io.sphere.sdk.client.ErrorResponseException: detailMessage: The locale
>   'en_US' is not part of the languages supported in this project

And I have this exception with any other locale.

My Merchant Settings:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the request. en-us is supported in Merchant Centre. You need to edit the languages (as per your picture) and add any languages you wish to maintain data for.

See Docs https://docs.commercetools.com/merchant-center/project-settings.html

Does that work for you?

Best Regards
Brian